# LoadRunner reg save parameter

Tags: loadrunner

I have string like this:

```
<a class="edit" name="Company2"` `onclick="javascript:editCompanyName(70,this.getAttribute('name')
```

I have to use the number 70. So if I use:

```
web_reg_save_param("com","LB=onclick=\"javascript:editCompanyName(",
      "RB=,", "Ord=ALL", "NotFound=WARNING","Search=body", "RelFrameId=1", LAST);
```

it works correctly and gives me list of existing numbers.

But when I want to take number 70, where `name="Company2"`,

```
web_reg_save_param("com","LB=name=\"Company2\" onclick=\"javascript:editCompanyName(",
      "RB=,", "Ord=ALL", "NotFound=WARNING","Search=body", "RelFrameId=1", LAST);
```

it gives me nothing.

Am I doing something wrong in second expression?

Please help me to find a problem, it is very important for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing two single quotes in your LB expression.

You have

> LB=name=\"Company2\" onclick=\"javascript:editCompanyName("

You need

> LB=name=\"Company2\"` `onclick=\"javascript:editCompanyName("